# More efficient to SELECT constants vs using VALUES when INSERTing a row with constant values?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-insert

Which of the following queries is the more efficient and the more idiomatic way of inserting a row with some constant values?

```
INSERT INTO example_table (col1, col2, col3)
SELECT 123, other_col, 'value' FROM other_table WHERE some_id = 999;
```

or

```
INSERT INTO example_table (col1, col2, col3)
VALUES (123,
       (SELECT other_col FROM other_table WHERE some_id = 999),
       'value');
```

Comment: The first method.

Comment: @GordonLinoff is there a reason for it performance-wise or is it just because the first one is shorter?

Comment: @ruohola how was this query created? I suspect there are other problems behind this.

Comment: @ruohola editing the query makes the comments half-wrong. The query will still break if two or more values are returned, it's still harder for people and the optimizer to work with it. `VALUES` is meant for *values*, not query results

Comment: @ruohola you didn't simplify the query, you changed it in an important way. Why are you trying to use this form in the first place?

Comment: INSERT with SELECT will insert from none to many rows, depending on what the SELECT returns. INSERT with VALUES will always insert one row, or raise an error if the SELECT returns more than one row.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I'm now wanting to use the `VALUES` way, just wanting to understand why it's the worse option.

Comment: @ruohola because it's not an option at all. It's meant to insert *values* not results. Yes, you can find a way to force it to work but it will be more complex, more fragile and most likely a lot slower - adding a `DISTINCT` or `TOP 1` for example will add a needless operation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

they have different semantics if there is not exactly one row matching the following query

```
SELECT other_col FROM other_table WHERE some_id = 999
```

so choose the one that gives you the semantics you want

- If the above query returns `0` rows do you want (a) no rows to be inserted or (b) a row with `NULL`?
- If the above query returns more than one row do you want (a) that number of rows to be inserted or (b) a runtime error?

If you answered (a) for both the above choose the first one. If you answered (b) choose the second one.